# Convert from max heap to min heap

Tags: heap

Got this heap:

```
         10
        /  \
       9    8
      / \  / \
     7  6  5  4
    / \ /
   3  2 1
```

And i'm going to show each step when i convert it to a minimum heap from maximum. I'm not sure how i do it, any help please? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to go throught tree by levels, starting with lowest node
If your heap is represented by array, it will be simple
1. step
comparing 1 with 6, and switching:

```
      10
     /  \
    9    8
   / \  / \
  7  1  5  4
 / \ /
3  2 6
```

next step - comparing 2 and 7 (and switching):

```
      10
     /  \
    9    8
   / \  / \
  2  1  5  4
 / \ /
3  7 6
```

next step - comparing 3 and 2 (and NOswitching):

```
      10
     /  \
    9    8
   / \  / \
  2  1  5  4
 / \ /
3  7 6
```

next step - comparing 4 and 8 (and switching):

```
      10
     /  \
    9    4
   / \  / \
  2  1  5  8
 / \ /
3  7 6
```

etc. this should create min-heap